# ROS Answers SE migration: PTAM Error

Tags: ros, ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got an Problem with my Current ROS. I download an current ROS Indigo 64 Bit VM from nootrix and i want to install the ptam package from ROS.

I have already done the catkin_make from ptam git repo.

But when i want to start the launcher with

roslaunch ptam cameracalibrator.launch

I got this error: [cameracalibrator.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ptam] nor is [ptam] a launch file name

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208085/ptam-error/) by [Nepitwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22291/nepitwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to source your workspace using the following command.

```
 source ~/your_catkin_workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

By that a new package is added to your path and thus known to the ROS environment.

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1